# Replace character in file name with regex python

Tags: python, regex, rename

My script should replace the "|" character of a file it finds via regex in a directory with an "l".

The code runs but filenames are not replaced. What is wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from posixpath import dirname
import re
import glob
import fnmatch

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m' 

#Path
file_src = dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#Current directory name
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + bcolors.BOLD + 'Directory:', file_src)
'\n'

#List all files in directory
list_file = os.listdir(file_src)
print(bcolors.BOLD + 'In this directory:', '\n', list_file)
'\n'

#Finding all the "|" characters in a string
file_pattern = re.compile('[\\":<>;|*?]*')


#Replace "|" with "l"
list = str(list_file)
re.sub(file_pattern, 'l', list, re.I)
```

Comment: You are not assigning the replacement result to any variable. Strings are immutable.

Comment: If you're trying to replace `|` characters, that regexp looks totally wrong.

Comment: @ekhumoro I tested with on https://pythex.org/ and it seems like working. What seems wrong?

Comment: @Trunks when you say "it seems like it's working" did you test for filenames that it *isn't* supposed to match? What about the filename `abc[]<>:;.csv`?

Comment: The "|" chracters are highlighted in green. And the code runs and ends without a change in the filenames. I tried with os.rename, but that gives me a "file not found" error.

Comment: @Trunks `re.sub('[\\":<>;|*?]*', 'l', 'fubar')` -> `'lflulblalrl'`.

Comment: @Trunks Jeez mate, don't just call `os.rename` without fully understanding what your code is doing first!

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for that! I'll look for `os.rename` alternatives

Comment: @Trunks I don't think you understood what ekhumoro was saying -- they're not saying that `os.rename` is the problem. The problem is that your code **probably (certainly?) isn't doing what you think it should**, so blindly using `os.rename` is **likely to cause problems**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Joshua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69898656/5730279) and the many comments, especially the [suggestions from ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69898448/replace-character-in-file-name-with-regex-python#comment123559562_69898448), already pointed out issues and guided to the solution.

### Fixed and improved

Here is my copy-paste ready code, with some highlighting inline comments:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from posixpath import dirname
import re
import glob
import fnmatch

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m' 
    RESET = '\u001b[0m' # added to get regular style

def print_list(files):
    '''Print a list, one element per line.'''
    for f in files:
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + f + bcolors.RESET)

#Path
directory = dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#Current directory name
print(bcolors.BOLD + 'Directory:' + bcolors.OKBLUE, directory)
print(bcolors.RESET)

#List all files in directory
files = os.listdir(directory)
print(bcolors.BOLD + 'In this directory:' + bcolors.OKBLUE, len(files), bcolors.RESET + 'files')
print_list(files)

#Finding all the "|" characters in a string
pipe_pattern = re.compile('\|')  # need to escape the special character pipe (in regex means logical-OR)


#Replace "|" with "l"
renamed_files = []
for f in files:
    f_renamed = re.sub(r'\|', 'l', f, re.I)
    if (str(f_renamed) != str(f)):
        renamed_files.append(f_renamed)

# print the list of filenames, each on a separate line
print(bcolors.BOLD, "Renamed:" + bcolors.OKGREEN, len(renamed_files), bcolors.RESET + "files")
print_list(renamed_files)
```

#### Explanation

- A simple regex to match a pipe-character is `\|`
- Note: prepended backslash is required to escape special characters (like `|` (or), `\` escape, `(` and `)` grouping etc.)
- Sometimes it is useful to extract code-blocks to functions (e.g. the `def print_list`) . These can be easily tested.

### Test your replacement

To test your replacement a simple function would help.
Then you can test it with a fictive example.

```py
def replace_pipe(file):
    return file.replace('|', 'l') # here the first argument is no regex, thus not escaped!

### Test it with an example first
print( replace_pipe('my|file.txt') )
```

If everything works like expected. Then you add further (critical) steps.

#### Avoid integrating the I/O layer to early

To elaborate on the [important advice from  ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69898448/replace-character-in-file-name-with-regex-python#comment123559562_69898448):
The `os.rename` is a file-system operation at I/O layer.
It has immediate effect on your system and can not easily be undone.

So it can be regarded as critical.
Imagine your renaming does not work as expected. Then all the files can be renamed to a cryptic mess, at worst (harmful like ransomware).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your example:

```py
list = str(list_file)
```

This line is

- [*shadowing* a reserved keyword](https://newbedev.com/can-i-use-the-variable-name-type-as-function-argument-in-python) in Python (don't name a variable `list`),
- I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing. It's not giving you a list of strings. It's giving you a string-representation of `list_file`, and
- your `list_file` is already a list of strings. I suspect you wrote this so that your `re.sub` function call would operate on a single thing, but you're better to use a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

On to the next line:

```py
re.sub(file_pattern, 'l', list, re.I)
```

You'll need to perform that `.sub` for each `str` in your `list_`, and assign the result to a variable:

```py
replaced_list_file = [re.sub(file_pattern, 'l', f, re.I) for f in list_file]
```

but as multiple commenters have said, is that compile pattern actually doing what you think it's doing? Have a look at [this link](https://regexr.com/695p2) and see if the results are what you expect.

Comment: `list_file` is already a list of strings, so your suggested code is redundant. Also, the OP's regexp is broken and won't give the results they are expecting. If all they want to do is replace the `|` characters, `result = [s.replace('|', 'l') for s in list_file]` will suffice.